# How do I implement my own data source with HTAutocompleteTextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

On gitub, they have a class called [`HTAutoCompleteTextField`](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField) that generates auto fill for `UITextFields`. My question is, how do I add my own data source to it?

The correct method, is obviously

```
- (NSString *)textField:(HTAutocompleteTextField *)textField completionForPrefix:(NSString *)prefix ignoreCase:(BOOL)ignoreCase
```

But, if I have an array of strings, how can I return the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data source method gets called every time the text changes in the `HTAutoCompleteTextField`. What you're doing in the method is filtering through your array of strings to find the string that best fits based on the input.

For example, we use it to autocomplete email address domain names. We have an array of various domains and we determine which domain best matches the text. Once we determine the best match, we return that string.

You can see an implementation of that method in `HTAutocompleteManager.m`.